# The server encountered an unexpected internal server error (generated by waitress) Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, web-applications

I am trying to host my website on heroku and I get the error on the hosted page as above. On running a traceback I get the following:

```
shashank@s-machine:~/development/hellowebapp$ heroku logs -t
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597710+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress/task.py", line 169, in service
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597711+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress/task.py", line 388, in execute
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597713+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 119, in __call__
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597712+00:00 app[web.1]:     app_iter = self.channel.server.application(env, start_response)
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597713+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.application(environ, start_response)
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597714+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597716+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 175, in get_response
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597716+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.get_exception_response(request, resolver, 404)
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597715+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.get_response(request)
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597717+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 90, in get_exception_response
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597718+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597718+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 268, in handle_uncaught_exception
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597721+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 45, in server_error
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597719+00:00 app[web.1]:     return callback(request, **param_dict)
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597722+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 74, in render
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597721+00:00 app[web.1]:     return http.HttpResponseServerError(template.render())
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597723+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209, in render
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597720+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 110, in _wrapped_view
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597723+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.template.render(context)
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597724+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._render(context)
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597724+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 201, in _render
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597725+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.nodelist.render(context)
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597720+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597725+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597727+00:00 app[web.1]:     return node.render(context)
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597726+00:00 app[web.1]:     bit = self.render_node(node, context)
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597727+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 917, in render_node
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597728+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 135, in render
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597728+00:00 app[web.1]:     return compiled_parent._render(context)
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597729+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 201, in _render
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597729+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.nodelist.render(context)
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597730+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597731+00:00 app[web.1]:     bit = self.render_node(node, context)
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597731+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 917, in render_node
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597732+00:00 app[web.1]:     return node.render(context)
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597732+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 105, in render
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597733+00:00 app[web.1]:     url = self.url(context)
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597734+00:00 app[web.1]:     return static(path)
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597734+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/templatetags/staticfiles.py", line 16, in url
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597735+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/templatetags/staticfiles.py", line 9, in static
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597736+00:00 app[web.1]:     return staticfiles_storage.url(path)
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597736+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 131, in url
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597737+00:00 app[web.1]:     hashed_name = self.stored_name(clean_name)
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597737+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 280, in stored_name
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597739+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 94, in hashed_name
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597739+00:00 app[web.1]:     (clean_name, self))
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597738+00:00 app[web.1]:     cache_name = self.clean_name(self.hashed_name(name))
2016-03-23T06:24:55.597740+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: The file 'images/favicon.png' could not be found with <whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7fed94e53a50>.
2016-03-23T06:25:08.874468+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=lit-fortress-70950.herokuapp.com request_id=952f7035-5cb7-4174-9439-a0767971e269 fwd="124.124.52.34" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=33ms status=500 bytes=269
2016-03-23T06:25:08.860148+00:00 app[web.1]: LOOK AT HERE >>> False
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887408+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:waitress:Exception when serving /
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887417+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887419+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress/channel.py", line 336, in service
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887420+00:00 app[web.1]:     task.service()
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887421+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress/task.py", line 169, in service
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887421+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.execute()
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887422+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress/task.py", line 388, in execute
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887423+00:00 app[web.1]:     app_iter = self.channel.server.application(env, start_response)
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887423+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 119, in __call__
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887424+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.application(environ, start_response)
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887425+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887432+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.get_response(request)
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887433+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in get_response
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887433+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887434+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 268, in handle_uncaught_exception
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887435+00:00 app[web.1]:     return callback(request, **param_dict)
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887435+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 110, in _wrapped_view
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887436+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887436+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 45, in server_error
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887437+00:00 app[web.1]:     return http.HttpResponseServerError(template.render())
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887438+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 74, in render
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887438+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.template.render(context)
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887439+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209, in render
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887439+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._render(context)
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887440+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 201, in _render
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887441+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.nodelist.render(context)
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887441+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887442+00:00 app[web.1]:     bit = self.render_node(node, context)
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887443+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 917, in render_node
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887443+00:00 app[web.1]:     return node.render(context)
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887446+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887447+00:00 app[web.1]:     bit = self.render_node(node, context)
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887447+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 917, in render_node
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887453+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 131, in url
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887448+00:00 app[web.1]:     return node.render(context)
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887454+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 280, in stored_name
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887449+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 105, in render
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887449+00:00 app[web.1]:     url = self.url(context)
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887444+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 135, in render
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887450+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/templatetags/staticfiles.py", line 16, in url
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887445+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 201, in _render
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887451+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/templatetags/staticfiles.py", line 9, in static
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887444+00:00 app[web.1]:     return compiled_parent._render(context)
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887451+00:00 app[web.1]:     return static(path)
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887446+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.nodelist.render(context)
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887452+00:00 app[web.1]:     return staticfiles_storage.url(path)
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887453+00:00 app[web.1]:     hashed_name = self.stored_name(clean_name)
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887454+00:00 app[web.1]:     cache_name = self.clean_name(self.hashed_name(name))
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887455+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 94, in hashed_name
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887456+00:00 app[web.1]:     (clean_name, self))
2016-03-23T06:25:08.887456+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: The file 'images/favicon.png' could not be found with <whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7fed94e53a50>.
```

I have the website running successfully on my localhost without the need modify anything. I even have favicon.png in my 'projectname/static/images' folder.

Settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'LOL'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'collection',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'registration',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'hellowebapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'hellowebapp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'testing@example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_PORT = 1025

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "home"


#Cookie name. this can be whatever you want
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME='sessionid'  # use the sessionid in your views code
#the module to store sessions data
SESSION_ENGINE='django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
#age of cookie in seconds (default: 2 weeks)
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE= 24*60*60*7 # the number of seconds for only 7 for example
#whether a user's session cookie expires when the web browser is closed
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE=False
#whether the session cookie should be secure (https:// only)
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=False
```

Comment: Try running (locally) `python manage.py collectstatic` and checking there are no errors.

Comment: Also, you definitely haven't posted your complete settings file, because the error message references `whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage` but the file you posted doesn't set `STATICFILES_STORAGE` anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for replying D. Evans, actually this is my complete code. Do I need to explicitly define my STATICFILES_STORAGE? I am not sure what it does?

Comment: Besides by default this will take the staticfiles present in "static" folder in each application and thats where I have put my files.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Actually the files were being ignored by the git since I had accidently added *.png to my ".gitingnore" file. Removing it solved the problem.